# Is there a way to have Firefox automatically log into a site?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

In Firefox is there any settings or add ons to automatically log you into a site? The site isn't extremely important (no money involved) so I wouldn't mind having firefox store the password even if slightly unsafe.

Comment: What kind of authentication? Simple username/password or something more complex like openID?

Comment: @terdon simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) will also accomplish this.

Comment: Adding to it, Lastpass is in fact quite secure even to use with sites involving money.

Comment: Is there an option to not sync certain passwords to there servers? I don't think anyone can convince me my passwords will be safe in there hands (but for unimportant things I don't really care).

Comment: Not sure if that's available with the free version.  It may be for their "premium" version.

Answer (score 1):

Give this Firefox plugin a try:

[AutoAuth](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autoauth/)

Note: it only works if you tell the browser to save your login creds.

This one may give you a little more control:

[The Idle Login](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-idle-login/)

Answer (score 1):

[PasswordBox](https://www.passwordbox.com/) is worth a try too.